# Kubernetes whitelist-source-range blocks instead of whitelist IP

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-compute-engine

Running Kubernetes on GKE

Installed Nginx controller with latest stable release by using helm.

Everythings works well, except adding the whitelist-source-range annotation results in that I'm completely locked out from my service.

Ingress config

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: staging-ingress
  namespace: staging
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: staging.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName:staging-service
            servicePort: 80
```

I connected to the controller pod and checked the nginx config and found this:

```
# Deny for staging.com/
geo $the_real_ip $deny_5b3266e9d666401cb7ac676a73d8d5ae {
    default 1;

    x.x.x.x 0;
    y.y.y.y 0;
}
```

It looks like he is locking me out instead of whitelist this IP's. But it also locking out all other addresses... I get 403 by going from staging.com host.

Comment: Just to clarify, this config will lock every request coming from an IP that's not x.x.x.x or y.y.y.y. And you are sending requests coming from those IP's that get 403 responses?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. However, I figured out by myself. Your service has to be enabled `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`. That means that the actual client IP should be used instead of the internal cluster IP.

To accomplish this run
`kubectl patch svc nginx-ingress-controller -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}'`

Comment: If this doesn't solve the entire problem, also restart your nginx controller pods. After that it should work.

Comment: Also note, if your nginx pod is running on different nodes than the destination services, this may break. You can solve this by setting it to run as a DaemonSet rather than Deployment, through a similar kubectl patch command.

Answer (score 9):

Your nginx controller service has to be set as `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`. That means that the actual client IP will be used instead of cluster's internal IP.

You need to get the real service name from `kubectl get svc` command. The service is something like:

```
NAME                                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
nobby-leopard-nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.0.139.37    40.83.166.29   80:31223/TCP,443:30766/TCP   2d
```

`nobby-leopard-nginx-ingress-controller` is the service name you want to use.

To finish this, run
`kubectl patch svc nobby-leopardnginx-ingress-controller -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}'`

When you setting up a new nginx controller, you can use the command below:

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress \
  --namespace kube-system \
  --set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local
```

to have a nginx ingress controller accept whitelist after installing.

Therefore if you configure your nginx controller with a `values.yaml` file please add this to it:

```yaml
controller:
  service:
    externalTrafficPolicy: "Local"
```

Comment: Which header would nginx whitelist against?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`, just set `real_ip_header` (via server-snippet) and use X-Forwarded-For header to retrieve and set client ip, or some other field, for example cloudflare is providing `CF-Connecting-IP`.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

Comment: Sorry, but no. I checked this and you still need to set `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`.